# Is there a better way to create acronym from upper letters in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, acronym

What is the best way to create acronym from upper letters in C#?

**Example**:

`Alfa_BetaGameDelta_Epsilon`

**Expected result**:

`ABGDE`

My solution works, but it's not nice

```
        var classNameAbbreviationRegex = new Regex("[A-Z]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        var matches = classNameAbbreviationRegex.Matches(enumTypeName);
        var letters = new string[matches.Count];

        for (var i = 0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        {
            letters[i] = matches[i].Value;
        }

        var abbreviation = string.Join(string.Empty, letters);
```

Comment: You can accept only one answer. I saw that you first accepted Tyler's answer and now mine. If you like multiple answers, accept the answer that you actually end up using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string.Join("", s.Where(char.IsUpper));
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right. However, string.Empty is preferred over "", ;P

Comment: @BartoszKP I think string.Empty vs. "" is a matter of personal preference

Comment: @BartoszKP: `string.Empty` is not prefered over `""`, that's just a coding guideline. There's no difference between the two.

Comment: I prefer `""` because its easier to type

Comment: Thanks, this is much better solution than my

Comment: I'm sorry, I referred to the incorrect `Join` overload, the actual overload used is [String.Join<T>(string, IEnumerable<T>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421.aspx) which is available since .NET 4.0.

Comment: But I think that the use of `Concat` is more intuitive than `Join` in this case.

Comment: @Steven: I actually think the overload you first posted is being used. It directly matches the return type of `Where`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: No, `String.Join<T>` is used. I checked this in VS.

Comment: @Steven: Sorry, you are correct. `Where` returns `IEnumerable<char>`, not `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Correctamundo :-)

Comment: @Steven And exactly because such a coding guideline exists, string.Empty is preferred. It's not a guideline just for sake of being a guideline. I'm not arguing that using "" is incorrect - it's just more readable to use constants then hard-coded strings.

Comment: @BartoszKP: There are several guidelines. Some force the use of `string.Empty`, others force the use of `""`. None if better, as long as you are consistent within the code base.

Comment: @Steven Could you provide a source with any guideline that forces usage of ""? I understand that it may be a strongly subjective topic, however for me it seems obvious that constants improve readability over hard-coded strings.

Answer (score 5):

```
string.Join("", s.Where(x => char.IsUpper(x))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
string test = "Alfa_BetaGameDelta_Epsilon";
string result = string.Concat(test.Where(char.IsUpper));
```

Comment: FYI http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/blog/development/c-string-concat-vs-string-join/

Comment: @SecretSquirrel: I don't think this really applies, because the blog post is actually using a separator which is not the case in this question.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth yes sorry you are right, and I just did the same test and Concat was quicker using an IEnmerable<string> with no separator :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Where` method to filter out the upper case characters, and the `Char.IsUpper` method can be used as a delegate directly without a lambda expression. You can create the resulting string from an array of characters:

```
string abbreviation = new String(enumTypeName.Where(Char.IsUpper).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 3):

By using MORE regexes :-)

```
var ac = string.Join(string.Empty, 
                     Regex.Match("Alfa_BetaGameDelta_Epsilon", 
                                 "(?:([A-Z]+)(?:[^A-Z]*))*")
                          .Groups[1]
                          .Captures
                          .Cast<Capture>()
                          .Select(p => p.Value));
```

More regexes are always the solution, expecially with LINQ! :-)

The regex puts all the `[A-Z]` in capture group 1 (because all the other `()` are non-capturing group `(?:)`) and "skips" all the non `[A-Z]` (`[^A-Z]`) by putting them in a non-capturing group. This is done 0-infinite times by the last `*`. Then a little LINQ to select the value of each capture `.Select(p => p.Value)` and the `string.Join` to join them.

Note that this isn't Unicode friendly... ÀÈÌÒÙ will be ignored. A better regex would use `@"(?:(\p{Lu}+)(?:[^\p{Lu}]*))*"` where `\p{Lu}` is the Unicode category UppercaseLetter.

(yes, this is useless... The other methods that use `LINQ` + `IsUpper` are better :-) but the whole example was built just to show the problems of Regexes with Unicode)

MUCH EASIER:

```
var ac = Regex.Replace("Alfa_BetaGameDelta_Epsilon", @"[^\p{Lu}]", string.Empty);
```

simply remove all the non-uppercase letters :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "Alfa_BetaGammaDelta_Epsilon";
var abbreviation = string.Join(string.Empty, str.Where(c => c.IsUpper()));
```