# How does "char.IsUpper" (without parentheses) work?

Tags: c#, .net

I just saw the following answer: [Is there a better way to create acronym from upper letters in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125738/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-acronym-from-upper-letters-in-c/18125805#18125805) and it has the following code:

```
string.Join("", s.Where(char.IsUpper));
```

How does the `char.IsUpper` work here? (Instead of `x => char.IsUpper(x)`)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`char.IsUpper` is a method group, which itself takes a `char` and returns a `bool`, so it's a valid predicate for use with `Where()`.

The code is referencing the method by name in much the same way as you would with any other method when specifying a delegate, instead of directly invoking it, so the parentheses aren't necessary.

The parentheses *are* necessary if you're wrapping it in a lambda expression `x => char.IsUpper(x)`, because you're *calling* the method and returning the result, *within* the expression.

Comment: @ispiro Rephrasing (this is not exactly correct, but hopefully helps clarify nonetheless): the parameter for `Enumerable.Where` has to be a function. It can be a function defined inline (`x => char.IsUpper(x)`), or it can be a preexisting function. `char.IsUpper` is a preexisting function, of the right type, so is a valid argument.

Comment: Is is some kind of polymorphism?

Comment: @Armen: No, it is not.

Comment: @hvd: No. `char.IsUpper` when used as is done here is *not* a function. It is a method group and a method group to delegate conversion is performed for the invocation to be legal.

Comment: @Jason It is not a function *call*. It *is* a function. You're right about the conversion to a delegate type, I intentionally omitted that from my comment to make it easier to understand and that is what I meant by "this is not exactly correct".

Comment: @hvd: No. When you write the syntax `s.Where(char.IsUpper)` the `char.IsUpper` that appears there is *not* a function. It is a method group: these are not the same thing.

Comment: @hvd: In this particular case where there is exactly one overload of `char.IsUpper` it's easy to get confused and think they are the same thing. But in a case like `Console.WriteLine` which has billions and billions of overloads, suddenly the difference becomes very obvious. When you have `void M<T>(Action<T> action)` and you say `M<int>(Console.WriteLine)` the `Console.WriteLine` there is a method group. The compiler performs a method group to delegate conversion using the overload `Console.WriteLine(int)` to do the conversion.

Comment: @Jason Actualy `Console.WriteLine` has 19 overloads

Comment: @Jason Given three functions, `bool f(int)`, `bool f(char)`, and `bool g(Predicate<int>)`, I would still say that the `f` in `g(f)` is a function. It is the first of these three. That same letter `f` could also refer to the second function in other contexts. Technically, you're completely correct, but you're being technically completely correct in a way that won't help people understand. You're treating the method group to delegate conversion as a single operation. I'm not saying that's incorrect, I am saying that isn't helpful.

Comment: @hvd: [Technically correct---the best kind of correct](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hou0lU8WMgo). :-)

Answer (score 3):

`char.IsUpper` refers to a [method group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/886822/what-is-a-method-group-in-c) which is passed to the `Where` function as a typed delegate via an implicit conversion which you can read in the [Covariance and Contravariance in C#, Part Three: Method Group Conversion Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/19/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-three-member-group-conversion-variance.aspx) article by Eric Lippert.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `char.IsUpper` (without parentheses) evaluates to a reference to the method, that can be passed as a predicate. If you added parentheses, that would just immediately invoke the method and attempt to pass the result instead of passing the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

[`Where<char>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx) takes a `Func<char, bool>` as a parameter.  By using `x => char.isUpper(x)`, you are creating a new `Func` to be used by `Where`.  However, the `toUpper` method, takes a `char`, and returns a `bool`.  Therefore, it can be used directly as the parameter for `Where`.

Comment: Either way it us a func - the difference is whether the func is to the IsUpper method, vs to an anonymous method which in turn *calls* IsUpper

Comment: That's what I was trying to say.  Sometimes words are hard.