# Finding all substrings in a string c# (Regex, Char Array?)

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string, parsing

I need to identify substrings found in a string such as:

"CityABCProcess Test" or "cityABCProcess Test"

to yield : [ "City/city", "ABC", "Process", "Test" ]

1. The first string in the substring can be lowercase or uppercase
2. Any substring with recurring uppercase letters will be a substring until a lowercase letter or space is found "ABCProcess -> ABC, ABC Process -> ABC"
3. If there is an uppercase letter followed by a lowercase letter the substring will be  everything until the next uppercase letter.

Can this be handled by regex? Or should I convert my strings to a character array and manually check these cases using some indexing logic. Would a lambda solution work here? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: This is going to be largely to your opinion, but IMO, when in doubt, don't use regex.  It may be faster (and if speed is of a huge concern, then it might be worth considering) but maintaining it is a headache usually.

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: "\\p{Lu}+" would be starting point of your regex... But it likely will be easier to just write code by hand. (Note that string is already indexable sequence of characters)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125738/is-there-a-better-way-to-create-acronym-from-upper-letters-in-c may be of help.

Comment: Implement a method that loops all characters in a `for-loop` and fills a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @user2366842: in most cases regex is  the slowest option.

Comment: Hmm...fair enough.  Then again, I don't try and include a bunch of logic on the rare occasions I do end up using regex, so there might be something to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pay no attention to the naysayers!  Even something like this really isn't that complicated with RegEx.  I believe this pattern should do the trick:

> [A-Z][a-z]+|[A-Z]+\b|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])|[a-z]+

See [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5BA-Z%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%7C%5BA-Z%5D%2B%5Cb%7C%5BA-Z%5D%2B(%3F%3D%5BA-Z%5D)%7C%5Ba-z%5D%2B&i=CityABCProcess%20Test%0D%0AcityABCProcess%20Test%0D%0ACityABCProcess%20TEST%0D%0ACity%20ABC%20Process) for a working demonstration.  It's just a bunch of `OR`'s processed in order.  Here's the breakdown:

- `[A-Z][a-z]+` - Any word that starts with an uppercase letter and then is followed by all lowercase letters
- `[A-Z]+\b` - Any word that is in all uppercase (so as to include the last uppercase letter which would be excluded in the following option)
- `[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])` - Any word that is in all uppercase, but not including the first uppercase letter of the next word
- `[a-z]+` - Any word that's all lowercase

For instance:

```
string input = "CityABCProcess TEST";
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append("[A-Z][a-z]+");
builder.Append("|");
builder.Append("[A-Z]+$");
builder.Append("|");
builder.Append("[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z])");
builder.Append("|");
builder.Append("[a-z]+");
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, builder.ToString()))
    {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
    }
```

Comment: Can confirm, @StevenDoggart is [some kind of wizard](https://regex101.com/r/mU2uH7/1) :-)

Comment: This is so close! Thanks for the reply. I am testing it using http://regexr.com/

I found it does not work in the case: "City ABC Process" it only gets "AB" instead of "ABC"

also leaves out numbers "Process 1"

Comment: [This example](http://ideone.com/DOGxPA) shows something similar.

Comment: Good point.  Fixed my answer to use `\b` instead of `$` to correct that.

Comment: What would have to be changed to have it recognize numbers as well, either apart of the substring or as a standalone? "Process1, Process 1"

Comment: You could use `([A-Z]|[1-9])` for uppercase and `([a-z]|[1-9])` for lowercase